# Dismissing MFMailComposeViewController Shrinks Done Button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a modally presented table view via a segue which has a done button.  One of the table entries then presents a MFMailComposeViewController which, when dismissed, leaves the done button in an odd state, as if it's shrunk?

I hope that makes sense?  Image below:

[image: Navbar with Shrunken Done Button]

Any assistance greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: are you changing done button frame anywhere in code ?

Comment: I guess you are doing something in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? It gets called if the view appears.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not directly, but in the App Delegate, I do have UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes but that shouldn't mess it up should it?

Comment: It appears to be the UILabel extension I've added that changes the font name for all labels so I don't have to manually do it -- surely the font has already had its type changed before appearing, so it shouldn't change anything in the viewWillAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews right?

Comment: The navigation buttons seem to be recreated each time they appear as  HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular and when I change the label, it doesn't layout the view appropriately afterwards.  I've hacked it for now so that it leaves the default font if the button is a "Cancel" "Send" or "Done" button which isn't ideal as it's the wrong font and is a terrible workaround, but I've got deadlines to meet right now...